# C# list of lists - how to make list in lists unique and edition resistant?

Tags: c#, nested-lists

this time I've got an C# programming issue:
I've got a list of lists:

```
List<List<string>> List1
```

And that list of strings in it:

```
List<string> List2
```

And, in loop, I want to put List2 in List1, but then, I want to change values in List2, but I don't want to change this values in the List2 which was inserted in List1.
Here is the example with pseudo-code of what I want to do (because I suppose nobody gets what I want at the moment):

```
List1 <=> ['one', 'two', 'three']
List2[1] <=> List1
List1.clear
List1 <=> ['four', 'five', 'six']
List2[2] <=> List1
```

but List1 changed in List2[1] too - I don't want that! It looks like now:

```
List2[1] <=> ['four', 'five', 'six']
List2[2] <=> ['four', 'five', 'six']
```

But I want that it will be:

```
List2[1] <=> ['one', 'two', 'three'] 
List2[2] <=> ['four', 'five', 'six']
```

What's the point? I want that these List1s stay in that state, what there were when I was inserting them to the List2. I hope someone will understand this and will help me.
I know that I'm inserting some kind of List1 pointners in List2, but how make it right? (right -> the way I want it to work^^)

Comment: what is the `<=>` syntax? Its not somethign I recognise...

Comment: @Chris you need to read the post again: ". . . Here is the example with pseudo-code . . . "

Comment: Mark: ah, ok. I generally would just use an equals or something there which is why I thought it might be something more interesting.

Comment: sorry for that! I thought it will be ok if I write it with this 'pseudo-code' :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to put a **copy** of `List1` in `List2`:

```
List2[1] = List1.ToList();
```

Otherwise, `List1`, `List2[1]` and `List2[2]` reference the same list, so by changing one, you're also changing the others.

Comment: exactly! I feel stupid, because solution was so simple -_-' That was fast, thank You!

Comment: I think this solution has the potential to hide some problems.  Why does List1 have to be the one you're adding to List2?  It sounds like you are calling some other function to get values into List1.  If that's the case, simply call that function inside the loop and assign the result to List2.  If the other function is setting List1 directly, then those are the problems that I'm talking about.  You have to learn to limit variable scope to what's necessary and your code will be a lot easier to maintain and read.

Comment: @Milimetric: I agree with you, List1 might not even be necessary. But without knowing what ofcapl wants to do exactly it's hard to give further advice.

Comment: unfortunately,I have to make List of Lists - but it is way too long to describe whole problem - in brief I'm working with 2 owl files and I extract it's class names, then if it is multiple-word names I divide them to single, searching for it's synonims from csv synonims file, and then searching words from both owl files, which can be combined (based on meaning) I hope I clarified a bit my work :)

Comment: @Meta-Knight: agreed.  @ofcapl: so your input on each pass of the loop is a string?  If you have an array of class names, what you described can be put into a list of lists like so: `string[] arrayOfNames = {"single", "name with multiple words", "another one"}; var yourListOfLists = arrayOfNames.Select(name => name.Split(" ")).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a new list for each item in the outer list.  Remember, you are placing a reference to the inner list in the outer list, not a copy.

```
 outerList.Add(new List<string>{"one", "two", "three"})
 outerList.Add(new List<string>{"four", "five", "six"})
```

Answer (score 1):

We understand.  The reason List1 is "changing" is because List1 is a pointer to a place in memory where its items are stored.  So when you assign List2[1] = List1, you're just creating another pointer called List2[1] to the same place in memory.

To accomplish what you're talking about, you'll have to create a new list each time you pass through the loop.  So for example:

```
List two = new List<List<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    List one = new List<string> {"one" + i, "two" + i, "three" + i};
    two.Add(one);
}
```

In each pass through this loop, List one will be a new object.  At the end, List two will have these values in it:

[["one1", "two1", "three1"], ["one2", "two2", "three2"], ... ]

You can generate the values any way you wish, but I was just showing an example of making them dynamic based on the loop counter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one answer I know. You have to do a deep-copy type of operation when you want to store a copy of a list rather than a reference to the original. Deep copy is unfortunately not part of the framework.

Via the commenter "karl" ( http://openmymind.net/ ) on the blog at http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2005/11/21/431125.aspx with my own edits to add to the example... you can serialize and deserialize the list, and you get a true copy of the list:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
// Do something to populate the list

BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

bf.Serialize(ms, strings);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
List<string> copy = (List<string>)bf.Deserialize(ms) ;
ms.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to translate this page to understand: http://leonelfraga.com/neomatrixtech/?p=412 
Note the code diferences and what is being printed in the dark boxes.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve your desired result, you need to store a copy of the list you wish to modify. You can do this either by creating a new list and adding the elements from the original in manually, or by using the extension method `ToList(...)`. This will create a copy of your original list, which will be stored, so you can then modify the original list without affecting the copy.

Comment: To the negative voters: I have changed my answer now as I re-read the question and realised I had misunderstood it. Please review the downvotes and comment if you feel they still stand.

Comment: Maybe you have looked at other answers and then updated your previous answer. Anyway, I wasn't the one who down voted in the first place ;)